# Por que @Html.CheckBoxFor retorna "true,false"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Na construção da minha View, tenho um campo do tipo:

```
public bool? RegistoGesOleos { get; set; }
```

Que represento usando o Razor como:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.RegistoGesOleos.Value)
```

Agora quando faço `submit` do meu Form, e tento ir buscar o valor do campo no Controller (usando o FormCollection):

```
var teste = form["ConcluidoGesOleos.Value"];
```

Recebo como:

> "true,false"

**Edit:**
Ao inspeccionar elementos na minha página, verifiquei que são criadas duas input's:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Value field is required." id="ConcluidoGesOleos" name="ConcluidoGesOleos.Value" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="ConcluidoGesOleos.Value" type="hidden" value="false">
```

Porque é que isso acontece e como posso contornar da forma mais correta?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso ocorre por causa da construção do html na página. O CheckBoxFor constroi algo similar a isso:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="RegistoGesOleos.Value" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="RegistoGesOleos.Value" value="false" />
```

Confira seu html formado na tela.

O Razor foi criado desta forma para prevenir a ausência do campo na serialização da página. Quando o checkbox não está selecionado o value dele não é incluído na serialização da página. Então você tem as seguintes situações:

1º - Caso checkbox esteja selecionado a serialização será: `RegistoGesOleos.Value=true,false`.
2º - Caso checkbox não esteja selecionado a serialização será: `RegistoGesOleos.Value=false`.

Se não existisse o input hidden seria:

1º - Caso checkbox estivesse selecionado a serialização seria: `RegistoGesOleos.Value=true`.
2º - Caso checkbox não estivesse selecionado a serialização seria:  (Nada).

**Como recuperar a informação:**
O `ModelBinder` recupera com perfeição estes valores para você. (Caso esteja utilizando algum ModelBinder) ou você pode, caso não esteja usando ModelBinder, fazer algo como:

```
var boolvalue = form["ConcluidoGesOleos.Value"].Contains("true");
```

**OBS:**
Caso não saiba você utiliza ModelBinder quando escreve algo no parametro do seu método action. ex:

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction(ModelRegistros model) { ... }
```

O objeto `model` é preenchido com os valores que vieram no request. Quem cria e preenche esse objeto é o ModelBinder.

Comment: exacto, é isso que está a acontecer

Comment: confira como tratar.

Comment: é exactamente isso ;)